# How to Set Universal Access -> Large Text on one screen

Tags: fonts

I have turned on the Large text option on my laptop, which works perfectly, as my laptop screen is rather small. However when I work on 2 screens, the text on the second screen is far too big, is there a way that I can set the large text setting to only apply to my laptop screen?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, I don't know enough to provide a solution. A workaround could be to change the resolution of your laptop screen, this is definitely not optimal, but might help.